# Babel's funny import

Tags: javascript, babeljs

Since no browser I know implements currently the ES6 modules interface - but transpilers do - I tested babel with this simple example

```
import { getUsefulContents } from "file.js";
getUsefulContents("http://www.example.com", data => {
  doSomethingUseful(data);
  });
```

I just wanted to see how does it transpile these lines. To my surprise it produced following output:

```
"use strict";

var _fileJs = require("file.js");

(0, _fileJs.getUsefulContents)("http://www.example.com", function (data) {
  doSomethingUseful(data);
});
```

The last line looks mysterious to me - especially the `(0, _fileJs.getUsefulContents)` part, what is going on there? What is the purpose of that `(0, ...)` on that line?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Calling a function like that forces it to call it in the global context.

```js
function whoAmI() {
  document.querySelector('pre').innerText += this.name + '\n';
}
window.name = 'window';
var mike = {
  name: 'mike',
  whoAmI: whoAmI
};
mike.whoAmI();
(0, mike.whoAmI)();
```

```html
<pre></pre>
```

The reason this works is because when it evaluates `(0, filesJs)` it runs through each of the statements in the parentheses, similar to how you can declare multiple variables using a `,`

```
var a = 1,
    b = 2,
    ...
```

As the last expression is reference to a function, it uses that when evaluating the function call with the next set of parentheses. Being that the expression was already evaluated, the `_filesJs` context is lost. It's effectively the same as doing this:

```
0; // Legal, just pointless
var f = _filesJs.getUsefulContents;
f("http://example.com", ...);
```

Comment: @NinaScholz good point and the reason why it has been used is for me still unclear

Comment: @TeroTolonen The reason is to prevent setting `this` inside of the function to `_filesJs` since you didn't call it that way when you wrote the ES6 code.

Comment: Ah, the "fat arrow" syntax, you mean

Comment: Just a small parentheses (heh). What it does is evaluates each statement in the parentheses, and returns the value of the last (in this case a reference to a function) which is later executed/called by the second set of parentheses. Just a tiny wording issue, otherwise ace answer.

Comment: oh, sorry, what was I thinking